# Gtkmm closing a gui window fro outside the class

Tags: c++, gtk, gtkmm

I am using Gtkmm package in Linux C++ for GUI Programming. I want to close one gui window from another class to call a gui function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

I think thois w'll help you to run and close widow from other window.

```
#include "currentWindow.h"
#include "NewWindow.h"

currentWindow::currentWindow() :
{
...
...
...

NewWindow NW;

// to run new window
    Gtk::Main::run(NW);  
//to close it 
   NW.hide();
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks your reply. But this not the solution what i asked. But i am really looking for automatic event generation from one gtkmm window gui class. based on this signal i can do whatever i want.